# Responsive table with 100% width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Here's code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">

    <table class="scroll wide">

      <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
        <td>Third</td>
        <td>Forth</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wide { width: 100%; }
```

Here's fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/emilcieslar/zc37ydys/

As you can see, there are 4 columns and scroll class that makes the table scrollable whenever the width of the page is smaller than the table width. However if I want to make the table width 100%, it stays the same, it doesn't stretch. I can see that the table tag itself is stretched, but the insides doesn't stretch. This is caused by table being display: block, however it has to be display: block, otherwise it won't be scrollable (on horizontal axis). How can I achieve 100% width table while still being responsive?

Comment: `td {
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: That would make all tds same width, which is undesirable as some of them should be proportionally smaller for they may contain less content than others. I updated the fiddle so it's more obvious what I mean. First column is much smaller than the rest of the columns.

Comment: Whoever gave this question & answer down one, please at least provide a comment.

Comment: I have been looking to a solution to this problem for days. @Aibrean is the only person to have a solution that actually works. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As they say, think out of the box, so I thought out of the table box and wrapped the table inside a container:

```
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
  <table class="my-table"><!-- without scroll class now -->
  ...
  </table>
</div><!-- /horizontal-scroll -->
```

with CSS:

```
.horizontal-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.my-table {
  min-width: rem-calc(640);
}
```

Incredibly simple solution, but took me a while to realise it. It's important to set min-width for the table as table width is by default flexible therefore it will never scroll if you don't set min-width. It will result in a shrank table to the point it's not possible to shrink anymore.

Comment: Hey Emil. I have the same issue ! what is this rem-calc(640) ?
is it the size of the table before being stretched ?

Comment: @EstelleChvl It's minimum width of the table. It should not shrink below this number, the actual value is up to you, but you have to set the `min-width` otherwise it shrinks completely. `rem-calc` is a utility function from foundation.